# Keeping the left/right scroll arrows in the tab bar in Firefox 5?

Tags: firefox

Is there some built in functionality in Firefox 5 (like in the main options dialog, or even in `about:config`) to make the left/right scroll arrows at the edge of the tab bar always be displayed instead of hidden when you have few tabs open, or do you need to edit `userChrome.css`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My extension, [FeatureFix](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/featurefix/), now contains an option in its configuration dialog ('tab behaviour / always show tabbar scroll buttons') to force the tabbar scroll buttons always to be displayed.